# Diff the output of the last two commands

Tags: bash, command-history, process-substitution

I frequently find myself doing something like the following:

```
$ big long command 1
$ big long command 2
$ diff -u <(big long command 1) <(big long command 2)
```

How can I get the shell (`bash` in my case) to construct that third command for me, without the need to cut and paste those big long commands into the `<()`s?  (It's obviously fine if the `big long command`s are re-executed; they are assumed to be safe to re-run.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the Bash shell's history to get those last 2 run commands like so:

```
$ big long command 1
$ big long command 2
$ diff -u <(!-2) <(!-1)
```

This will take the current command minus 2 (`big long command 1`) and the current command minus 1 (`big long command 2`) and run them into `diff`.

#### References

- [15 Linux Bash History Expansion Examples You Should Know](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/08/bash-history-expansion/)

Comment: also, you can pipe the output to diff if you wanted (although in this case may not have sense if you want to view the complete output before diffing): `$ big long command 1; $ big long command 2 | diff -u <(!-1) -`